# Pages, aside from admin-side and the home page, read "500 Internal Server Error - nginx/1.1.19".

Tags: nginx, 500-internal-error

I've set up a WordPress website. I'm able to login, and browse the front page- but everything but the admin-side brings me to a white page with the texts "500 Internal Server Error - nginx/1.1.19". I've read up on this and can't seem to solve the issue. I'm unable to find the .htaccess, even with my FileZilla forcing the showing of hidden files. I read that you may have to enable 'fancy' permalink, so I did, but it held no results.

Comment: The nginx server does not use .htaccess files. You need to speak to your host to find out what is causing the 500 errors, or to look at the server's error logs.

Comment: I've been told by my host that it isn't managed and that because of this they are unable to help me out. They did point me out to a Google search results page, but no cigar. Thank you for your help, I'm glad I know that now! I will search on

Comment: They can still give you the error logs, regardless of whether or not it is a managed host. Without looking at the actual error message, you cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

nginx doesn't use the .htaccess file for configuration.  Have you checked the wordpress Codex for specific instructions for setup when using nginx instead of straight apache?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx